# Python, how to unroll tuples in lambda?

Tags: python, lambda

I have 2 equal-length lists and I am trying to get scalar product of them with, but it does not work this way:

```
sum(map(lambda a,b: a*b, zip(list1, list2)))

error: TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Even if this code is not good for my task, is there any way to force lambda to work with tuples for such cases?

i'd like to do something like

```
lambda x: (a,b)=x;a*b
```

But it will not work with C-style ';' )

Thank you for answers, still need to learn many things about Python )

Answer (score 19, accepted):

well, you don't need a lambda for this...

```
sum(a*b for a, b in zip(list1, list2))
```

even `zip()` is slightly less than perfect... to avoid creating a list, either use python3, or `itertools.izip`:

```
sum(a*b for a, b in itertools.izip(list1, list2))
```

but if, for some craaaaazy reason, you really really wanted to use lambda, pass each list to map seperately:

```
sum(map(lambda a, b: a*b, list1, list2))
```

and even then, you didn't need a lambda either, a callable product is available in the `operator` module:

```
sum(map(operator.mul, list1, list2))
```

but use the generator in the first or second example, it will usually be faster.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply write

```
sum(a*b for a,b in zip(list1, list2))
```

or use map correctly:

```
sum(map(lambda (a,b): a*b, list1, list2))
```

`map` does zip it's arguments, in fact `zip( .. )` is just `map(None, ..)`.

You can also unpack arguments when the function is called in Python2, but this unusual feature was removed in 3:

```
sum(map((lambda (a,b): a*b), zip(list1, list2)))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `operator` module ([docs](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html)):

```
 sum(map(lambda item: operator.mul(*item), zip(list1, list2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sum(x[0]*x[1] for x in zip(list1, list2))
```

List comprehensions and generator expressions are the proper way.

Comment: That isn't a list comprehension, though, it's a generator expression.

Answer (score 2):

*Answering OP's original question about lambda accepting multiple arguments through zip.*

You need to use parentheses around `lambda` arguments, like so:

`sum(map(lambda (a,b): a*b, zip(list1, list2)))`

Tested on Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

```
(lambda x:  x[0] == ... and x[1] != ..... , mylistoftuples )
```

The tuple is just a normal element of a list so

```
x <- {tuples...}
```

So then `x` can just be treated as a normal tuple of `(x1,x2,x..,xk)` like any other assigned tuple variable.