# Printing Multiple Lists using Format

Tags: python, list, format

I am having 2 lists with variable sizes that need to be printed alongside each each other. For instance, if

```
A = [30, 40, 50]
B = [1,2,3]
```

Then, I want to print an output that looks like:

```
A 30 B 1 A 40 B 2 A 50 B 3
```

I have tried something similar to

```
print (len(A)* ('A {} B {}').format(*A,*B)
```

but this does not give me what I am looking for.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) both lists:

```
A = [30, 40, 50]
B = [1,2,3]

result = ' '.join('A {} B {}'.format(a, b) for a, b in zip(A, B))
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
A 30 B 1 A 40 B 2 A 50 B 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple iteration with `enumerate`

**Ex:**

```
A = [30, 40, 50]
B = [1,2,3]

print(" ".join("A {} B {}".format(v, B[i]) for i,v in enumerate(A)))
```

**Output:**

```
A 30 B 1 A 40 B 2 A 50 B 3
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solution:

```
print(*map(lambda x, y: "A {} B {}".format(x, y), A, B))
```

`lambda x, y` - lambda function takes 2 arguments (each element from `A` and `B`) and create a data structure called `map` (similar to list). After this, we treat `map`-like data structure as a regular `list` and print each specific element.

**Input**

```
A = [1, 2, 3]
B = [4, 5, 6]
```

**Intermediate  result**

*For explanation purpose, exclusively.*

```
print(*map(["A 1 B 4", "A 2 B 5", "A 3 B 6"]))
```

**Output**

```
A 1 B 4 A 2 B 5 A 3 B 6
```

In case when one of the arrays will be shorter, it will return the following:

**Input**

```
A = [1, 2]
B = [4, 5, 6]
```

**Output**

```
A 1 B 4 A 2 B 5
```

For more details, take a look on [map](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#map).

Inspired by [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812574/python-how-to-unroll-tuples-in-lambda)